# Laravel Elasticsearch

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

Please I try to make an elasticsearch on my Laravel 5.8 project. So first I install elacticseach in my macOs:

```
brew install elasticsearch
```

The elasticseach server work fine http://localhost:9200/:
[image]

After that, I create a new laravel project and I download this package: **[cviebrock/laravel-elasticsearch](https://github.com/cviebrock/laravel-elasticsearch#)**

But I didn't figure it out, Any one please hase use elasticsearch with laravel before, can give me an example or anys documentations. Thank's.

Comment: Did you follow the Installation and Usage steps on the Github page? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Thank you for reponding, I follow the steps of installation, but they dont have and integation simple demo. I try to make the link with my application

Comment: Asking for tutorials and guides is generally off topic in SO. Please try doing some intensive Googling instead, that will always yield better results than anything we can ever suggest.

Comment: trust me I do my best for that. No clear idea for now...

Answer (score 0):

you need first install elasticsearch :

```
wget -qO - https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https

echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/5.x/apt stable main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-5.x.list

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install elasticsearch
```

Restart the service :

```
sudo service elasticsearch restart
```

if isn't workin please edit the following file

```
 /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
```

change `network.host: localhost` and restart the service again

**UPDATE**

if you are sure that your elasticsearch work fine ( by typing the elasticsearch in your terminal )

considere the following steps :

add  scout driver : 
`composer require babenkoivan/scout-elasticsearch-driver`

in  the providers section at your config/app.php  add the two classes :

```
   Laravel\Scout\ScoutServiceProvider::class,

   ScoutElastic\ScoutElasticServiceProvider::class,
```

edit your env with `SCOUT_DRIVER=elastic`

run the following commands :

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laravel\Scout\ScoutServiceProvider"
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="ScoutElastic\ScoutElasticServiceProvider"
```

Comment: Thank you for you anser, but the elasticsearch server is working fine, when I access to [http://localhost:9200/] I get all informations. But now i try to make the link with my Laravel apllication.

Comment: can you update your question and gives us the error you have

Comment: I dont have error, I just can't start with the package.

Comment: @MalekBenelouafi check the update , you can work with Scout

Comment: Do you think Scout package is more better, did you have any git project sample please. thank you so much.

Comment: @MalekBenelouafi yes https://medium.com/@felixgondwe/elasticsearch-setup-using-homebrew-2017891f62bb

Answer (score 0):

For monolog driver and ruflin/elastica:2.3.3, laravel 5.8 with php 7.4 and elasticsearch 7.13

https://github.com/ruflin/Elastica/discussions/1999